# how to fix vscode extension elixirls alert "OTP compiled without EEP48 documentation chunks"?

Tags: vscode-extensions, elixirls

This is the alert I am getting and I don't know how to fix it...[image]

I created new bug for it on [`their github`](https://github.com/elixir-lsp/vscode-elixir-ls/issues/284) (providing a bit more details in there), but I am not sure if it is bug, or I am doing sth wrong.

Answer (score 55):

As nobody posted the answer from that Github issue yet, here it is (when using `asdf`):

Setting the environment variable `KERL_BUILD_DOCS=yes` when installing the Erlang should fix it.

Example: `KERL_BUILD_DOCS=yes asdf install erlang 25.1.2`

Comment: I didn't see the thread, and so you saved me!

Answer (score 13):

I have an `Erlang 25.3 / Elixir 1.14.4-otp-25` global installation on Ubuntu 22, which I installed with **asdf**. Here's a list of all [asdf commands](https://asdf-vm.com/manage/commands.html).

This is what I did:

1. In VSCode, uninstall ElixirLS extension
2. Close VSCode
3. In terminal, you can check erlang versions installed with: `asdf list erlang`
4. In terminal, remove erlang with: `asdf uninstall erlang 25.3`
5. In terminal, check erlang is removed with: `asdf list erlang`
6. In terminal, reinstall erlang with: `KERL_BUILD_DOCS=yes asdf install erlang 25.3`
7. In terminal, set erlang as global with: `asdf global erlang 25.3`
8. In terminal, you can check erlang versions installed with: `asdf list erlang`
9. Open VSCode in an elixir project.
10. In VSCode, install the ElixirLS extension.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Why does one need to uninstall/reinstall VSCodium extension? Or does one?

Answer (score 0):

Check the asdf erlang plugin [Before install title](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-erlang?tab=readme-ov-file#before-asdf-install)! E.g. on macOs, depending on the target Erlang version you may `brew install wxwidgets libxslt fop` to compile doc, and use observer and debugger.